# How to sort bucket result based on viewed_timestamp in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elastic Search. I want to find the top 10 unique recent visited doc_id.

I have done first aggregation on doc_id and added sub-aggregation to sort each group and get a single result.  Now I want to sort this bucket.
I am not able to sort the bucket's result based on view_timestamp. How can I add order during first aggregation?

I have tried other solutions given on stack overflow, but it is not working for me. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

---

Query

```
{
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "term": { "username": "nil@gmail.com" }
            }
        }
    },

    "size":0,
    "aggs":{
        "title": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "doc_id",
                "size":0
            }
            ,
            "aggs": {
                "top": {
                    "top_hits": {
                       "sort": [
                        {
                            "viewed_timestamp": {
                                "order": "desc"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                        "size": 1

                    }
                }
            }        

        }

    }    

}
```

---

Bucket result:

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "title": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [{
                "key": "b003",
                "doc_count": 3,
                "top_tag_hits": {
                    "hits": {
                        "total": 3,
                        "max_score": null,
                        "hits": [{
                            "_index": "visitedData",
                            "_type": "userdoc",
                            "_id": "AVak51Sp",
                            "_score": null,
                            "_source": {
                                "viewed_timestamp": "20160819T152359",
                                "content_type": "bp",
                                "title": "Data print",
                                "doc_id": "BP003"
                            },
                            "sort": [
                                1471620239000
                            ]
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "key": "bp004",
                "doc_count": 3,
                "top_tag_hits": {
                    "hits": {
                        "total": 3,
                        "max_score": null,
                        "hits": [{
                            "_index": "visitedData",
                            "_type": "userdoc",
                            "_id": "AVak513Y8G",
                            "_score": null,
                            "_source": {
                                "viewed_timestamp": "20160819T152401",
                                "content_type": "bp",
                                "title": "Application Print",
                                "doc_id": "BP004"
                            },
                            "sort": [
                                1471620241000
                            ]
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is beacuse your view_timestap type is not date, it is timesatmp. you should change this field to date format, such as:
`"updateTime": "2017-01-12T21:28:49.562065"`

Answer (score 0):

If you're only trying to order by the timestamp, you could try using a *max* aggregation, like in this example:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html#_field_collapse_example